# JQuery .load() function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below doesn't  load content of html page to div, only display alert. Can you tell what wrong with it, please?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js">
</script>

<script >
$( document ).ready(function() {

            $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
                $( "#content" ).load( "registration.html" );
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#">JQUERY</a>
<div id="#content">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"JQuery .load() function doesnt work"* Yes, it does.

Comment: Note that `load` uses Ajax, and some browsers do not allow using Ajax when there is no web server. This is probably the next problem.

Comment: Also, make sure you are loading the right path to the file.. in your case, is registration.html in the same folder? if not change to the correct path

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder. I am using Apache2.4 web server does it need to install some additional modules to it, for AJAX start working? What web server is needed, Vohuman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your div's ID is `#content`, change it to just `content`. (only in the html, **NOT** in the jQuery selector)

Comment: Thank you for quick respond! I changed but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Pavel in your browser, press F12 and open up the javascript console to check if you aren't getting any errors

Comment: This is my error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/My%20Websites/registration.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @Pavel: So you are running a webserver, but your browsers address bar shows e.g. *file:///D:/My%20Websites/index.html* ? So it's not using the webbrowser. Surf to **http://localhost** to see the pages from your local webserver and navigate to the starting html file. Then the AJAX loading should find your registration file.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
<div id="#content">
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```